# Extended Module/Group Documentation in external file

Tags: c, doxygen

I have a maybe simple problem, but my Google-Fu produced no results.

I have a doxygen documented header file like this:

```
/**
 * @file filename.h
 *
 * @date today
 * @author me
 *
 *  @defgroup mygroup grouptitle
 *  @brief my nice functions
 *
 *  Here is a medium sized description, 4-5 lines, which outline the
 *  functions and the way these functions work together, what is init,
 *  what is the main function of this module and maybe additional
 *  information on used hardware (as it is mainly embedded software).
 *
 *  Here starts another description block, typical length around 20-50
 *  lines. Detailed Hardware description, code snippets as examples and
 *  so on. I want to remove this section from the header file and
 *  replace it by something like
 *  /special_doyxgen_command_to_insert extended_doc_mygroup.md
 *
 *  \addtogroup mygroup
 *  @{
 */

here are function definitions, enums, defines and what else

/** @} */
```

I have no idea if this is possible but I have an additional mygroup.md in which some examples are given and and the general usage is shown. Depending on the file it has 10 - 50 lines, mostly 1 or 2 code examples.

In the past I inserted the examples in the header/sourcefiles, but I don't like that approach, so I created a markdown file and linked to this via the doxygen ref functions.
What I would like is a 'insert' tag that inserts the .md contend in the 'Detailed Description' Section of my Group Documentation (the HTML and Latex files).

Is there such a command (or a set of commands to get my approach?)

Comment: a couple of observations: 1) a header file is for extracting/localizing information that is needed across multiple files,  There fore it should not contain a source file.  2) a `defgroup` tag should be in the local doxygen init file, not buried in a header file.

Comment: ah, I see that this may be badly written: I have a *.h with the code above, including the `/defgroup mygroup title` statement, followed by the `/addgroup mygroup`. "here comes my code" is all the definitions, no declaration, no actual functions. these are in a *.c file. I don't see the condition of a doxygen init file in the documentation [here](https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/grouping.html). I edit my inital question to make it more clear.

Comment: the doxygen manual at: <https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/starting.html>, second paragraph says: "Optionally, the executable doxywizard can be used, which is a graphical front-end for *editing the configuration file that is used by doxygen* and for running doxygen in a graphical environment. For Mac OS X doxywizard will be started by clicking on the Doxygen application icon."

Comment: My error, the `defgroup` can be in an doxygen comment block,  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many commands existing to include external code examples in your documentation. Have a look at configuration tag `EXAMPLE_PATH` and the special commands `@include` and `@snippet`. You could create a directory called "examples" where you put your example files into and tell doxygen by entering this directory in the `EXAMPLE_PATH` tag:

```
EXAMPLE_PATH  = ./examples
```

Then you create some example files, e.g: examples_1.c

```
/// [Example1]
/// Here some more text to explain the example which is not shown by the \@snippet command.

// But normal comments are shown as a part of the code
for(;;)
{
     doSomething();
}
/// [Example1]

/// [Example2]
while(1)
{
    doSomething2();
}
/// [Example2]
```

Now you can add these code snippets using the `@snippet` command in your group documentation:

```
/**
* @defgroup ...
* ...
* @snippet examples_1.c Example1
* ...
* @snippet examples_1.c Example2
*/
```

Alternatively you can include the code of a whole source file:

```
/**
* ...
* @include examples_2.c 
* ...
*/
```

Another aprroach you should look at is the usage of the `@copydoc` and `@copydetails` command.

Hope this answers your question.